# Equal sign/Assignment Operator inside statement

Tags: c++, c

I was browsing github the other day and found this piece of code in C++.

```
order[i]= order[i]+order[r]-(order[r]=order[i]);
```

Why is there 2 equal signs in a line of code? I have never seen this before.

Comment: It means that you shouldn't do this. Expunge this line of code from your memory, and pretend that you never saw it. This is not exactly a stellar example of good programming practices.

Comment: @desertSniper87  There are two equal signs that to make undefined behavior of the program.:)

Comment: On other note, this piece of code just swaps order[i] and order[r].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The assignment operator `=` [returns an `LVALUE`, meaning a value can be further assigned to it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14697643/low-level-details-of-c-c-assignment-operator-implementation-what-does-it-retu).

Further, this is poor coding in general, as it's hideous. The author would be better off doing separate assignments over multiple lines, as it's easier to read, less prone to errors while implementing (as an extension of readability), the optimizer will likely generate similar code in either case, etc. Also, this kind of code often leads to a common duplicate question on SO: [sequence points, and why this code is horrible.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4176328/undefined-behavior-and-sequence-points)

**Edit**: [And as others have pointed out, it invokes UB. Axe it.](http://blog.llvm.org/2011/05/what-every-c-programmer-should-know.html)

Comment: So I should refractor the code into this:

temp = order[r];
order[r] = order[i];
order[i]= order[i]+temp-order[r];

Comment: It's not only hideous, but it's even undertermined.  So yes, refactor it.

Comment: @desertSniper87 Yes, something like that. It's now much easier to see the **intent** of your code.

Answer (score 1):

In C and C++ the assignment [operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operators_in_C_and_C%2B%2B) is just an operator like any other.  It returns the object on the left side of the assignment.

So the parentheses at the end copy `order[i]` into `order[r]` and uses then `order[r]` with its new value.

**Very important remark:** The result of this expression is undetermined: it is [not guaranteed that the operands of the operator are evaluated from left to right](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25323426/3723423) lke in some other languages. It is then compiler dependent, if the second term uses `order[r]` before or after the assignment in the third term. So there are 2 possible results.